# I want to see the details of how a sumifs value was created

Tags: google-sheets

I have a budget sheet that uses SUMIFS to calculate a total for a particular category. it uses a separate transaction sheet of individual rows to calculate the value for a given category and month. I want to be able to click on my budget total and see what values were used to create this SUMIFS value. Any ideas on how or if this can be done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 0):

Choose **Insert > Sheet**, and copy your `sumifs()` formula into cell `A1` there. Then edit the formula to replace `sumifs()` with `filter()`, like this:

`=sumifs(Data!G2:G, Data!F2:F, "deal", Data!G2:G, "<= 42")`

...becomes:

`=filter(Data!A2:G, Data!F2:F = "deal", Data!G2:G <= 42)`